How many bits are the data bus pins connected to L1 Cache and CPU in Typical Embedded System?
When studying computer architecture in college, I learned that the data bus pins connecting the CPU and L1 cache for data transmission are sized according to the register bit size. For example, in a 64-bit system, I understand that the data bus pins between the CPU and L1 Cache are 64 bits.
However, in modern embedded systems, the internal cache typically adopts a banked structure, allowing parallel Load/Store of data for each bank. Even if more than 64 bits of data are fetched in parallel from the banks, the data bus pins are still 64 bits. Consequently, the values will be updated sequentially in the registers.
So, to avoid sequential data transmission, is the increase in the number of data bus pins from the conventional 64-bit to a form like 64 * N bits being considered?

"Modern" embedded systems range from 8-bit 8051 microcontrollers to 64-bit AArch64, RISC-V, or even x86-64.  (e.g. https://www.amd.com/en/solutions/automotive/in-vehicle-experience.html advertizes a line of Ryzen Embedded CPUs designed for in-vehicle entertainment / media.  Tesla uses this, perhaps also as part of its autopilot stuff.)  In modern AMD CPUs (since Zen 2), the path between L1d and load/store execution units is 256 bits wide (32 bytes) https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/microarchitectures/zen_2#Block_Diagram .

In many AArch64 CPUs, it's 128-bit wide, allowing atomic ldp/stp and efficient SIMD vector load/store.  Of course many low-end microcontrollers don't have cache at all, including some 64-bit ones like Cortex-M23 and M33, and even on higher-end Cortex-M the caches are still optional (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Silicon_customization)
